# New dryer belt is different and now slips.

Tags: dryer

I replaced all the moving parts in the dryer minus drum and motor. Drum turns freely by hand.I have the older maytag dryer where the flat side of belt rides against drum. New belt has cloth on backside. Old belt didnt. Now it slips under heavy load. Do they make the correct belt for this dryer?

Comment: You really didn't really give us anything to go with on this question. Not all dryers are the same, in fact, few ever are. Make sure the belt is on the same way the diagram directs it as provided by the dryer manual (especially around the tensioner!). Regarding do they make the right belt... Did you buy the replacement part for the dryer that was specified? if so, then you already have your answer to that question. If you didn't, then how on earth did you pick the belt you bought?

Comment: Is there a tensioner anywhere in the system?

Comment: There are spray-on products for increasing belt grip and reducing squeal, but they may not be compatible with your belt's material or the head inherent in a dryer.  Read the labels before purchase.

Answer (score 1):

> "Do they make the correct belt for this dryer"?

If only there was a way for us to know what dryer you have. hmmmm, and My tinfoil hat that lets me divine what dryer you own is not working at the moment, ( the belt is slipping ).

Write down manufacturer's name, model name and number.

Open your favorite internet search engine ( i use duckduckgo, they do not track you ) and type in the manufacturer's name and model name and number.

Locate the correct part from an aftermarket parts supplier or the manufacturer's web site and contact them.